# A disc (with its plane vertical) of radius 1m rotates about a horizontal axis passing through its center by 60 degrees.

Tags: triangles

If P was the highest point on the disc initially then finally P gets lowered by

A)$\frac 14$m

B)$\frac 12$m

C)$\frac 13$m

D)$\frac 35$m

I am not able to understand the question, so it would be helpful if anyone can tell me the general idea of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a high-quality artistic representation of the scenario:

[image]

Comment: It’s pretty high quality, really.